# How does C17 want me to initialize my atomics?

Tags: c, atomic, c17

The C17 standard deprecates `ATOMIC_VAR_INIT` from `stdatomic.h`, meaning it still supports it but would rather it not be used. What is the correct non-deprecated way of initializing atomics in C17?

Same as non-atomic types:

```
atomic_int foo = 42;
```

Or something new?

Comment: The [ISO C working group website](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/) dosn't contain any information about a C17 standard. Do you mean C++?

Comment: Looking at the corresponding defect report ([DR 485](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2148.htm#dr_485)) I would say that your example is correct (though I don't know enough about the standard to be sure)

Comment: @s7amuser No I mean C. Apparently C17 is a minor revision to the C11 standard rather than a whole new standard, which may be why it isn't listed as a standard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C17 makes it ok to initialize atomics using the usual explicit initialization:

```
atomic_int n = 42;
```

C17 literally just dropped the two words "using ATOMIC_VAR_INIT" from the sentence in 7.17.2.1.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [that document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2148.htm#dr_485), section **DR 454**, using the macro makes it impossible to know in which state is the variable.

```
atomic_int guide1 = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(42); /* known value(42); WHAT STATE? */
```

But using the normal assignment is also undetermined, as shown bellow.

```
atomic_int guide2;        /* indeterminate value; indeterminate state */
atomic_int guide3 = 42;   /* known value(42); indeterminate state */
```

To put your variable in a known state, you have either to use `static` or the [`atomic_init`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_init) function.

```
static atomic_int guide4;  /* known value(0); valid state */
static atomic_int guide5 = 42; /* known value(42); valid state */
atomic_int guide6;
atomic_init(&guide6, 42); /* known value(42); initialized state */
```

But that's the only information I could find.

Comment: The "normal" initialization is what changed in C17.